# How do I get rid of the whitespace above my 'subscribe to our newsletter' section

Tags: html, css

I want to get rid of the whitespace between the 'subscribe to our newsletter' section and the 'Affordable Professional Web Design' section.

I have already tried to set the margin to 0 for the bottom of the 'Affordable Professional Web Design' section and also the top margin for the 'subscribe to our newsletter' section but that doesn't seem to work.

This is how it looks like in a browser:

[image]

This is my HTML and CSS file:

```css
.webdesignbannerdiv {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.webdesignheader {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.webdesignparagraph {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/*newsletter section*/

.newsletterdiv {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #35424a;
}
```

```html
<section id="affordablewebdesignbanner">
  <div class="webdesignbannerdiv">
    <h1 class="webdesignheader">Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
    <p class="webdesignparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id=subscribetonewsletter>
  <div class="newsletterdiv">
    <h1>Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
      <button type="submit" class="newsletterbutton">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is how i want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a *complex* `margin-collapsing` as the `p` element has a default `margin-bottom` that is rendred outside of the section even if this one is having a `min-height` set. You may notice that this won't happen in all the browsers (on Firefox you won't see this gap).

To fix this, simply remove that margin:

```css
.webdesignbannerdiv {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.webdesignheader {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.webdesignparagraph {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}


/*newsletter section*/

.newsletterdiv {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #35424a;
}
```

```html
<section id="affordablewebdesignbanner">
  <div class="webdesignbannerdiv">
    <h1 class="webdesignheader">Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
    <p class="webdesignparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id=subscribetonewsletter>
  <div class="newsletterdiv">
    <h1>Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
      <button type="submit" class="newsletterbutton">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```